# What is this early-flowering tree?

Tags: identification, trees

I always wanted to know what this early-flowering tree is, but was afraid to ask, since it must be some common tree, and I would look so stupid if I asked. But now I am finally asking you. :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Prunus spinosa, common name Blackthorn, maybe - that's one of the earliest to put out blossom, usually before much else does and even while snow is on the ground. Good close up image of blackthorn flowers in this link for you to compare http://www.wildlifeinsight.com/3563/whats-the-difference-between-blackthorn-and-hawthorn/

Comment: Yes, thanks, blackthorn is indeed a strong candidate, and is a native and frequent tree in my area. I added more photos of flowers, however, even on the same branch, they can have different coloration, esp. in the middle part, which makes identification by flowers very difficult, at least to me.

Comment: Ever seen sloe berries on it? Keep  a check later in the year, see if they form, that will confirm or deny the ID